# Are there any IoT Systematic Creation Security Checklists?

Tags: hardware, software, programming, iot

Are you aware of any publicly available documents that would help IoT/Connected product creators develop a systematic/programmatic approach and/or process to securing such new age devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A note about the wording of the question. You've asked about IoT but this is more of a concept than a "thing". IoT might cover many subjects from industrial controls to smart cities with home automation in between.

However, the following may be of help.

- The Cloud Security Alliance's "[Future Proofing The Connected World](https://cloudsecurityalliance.org/download/future-proofing-the-connected-world/)" report
- NIST's "[Network of Things](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-183.pdf)" report
- [The EU's emerging IoT policy](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-single-market/en/internet-things)
- [Robert Silvers](https://www.dhs.gov/person/robert-silvers), the Assistant Secretary for Cyber Policy at the U.S. Department of Homeland Security has some [useful things to say](http://www.networkworld.com/article/3123039/security/homeland-security-issues-call-to-action-on-iot-security.html).
- A [presentation from an ENISA workshop](https://www.enisa.europa.eu/events/copy_of_enisa-workshop-on-cyber-security-for-iot-in-smart-home-environments/1-enisa-securing-europes-iot-devices-and-services) at least highlights some of the EU thinking that is happening
- The UK Government have a [competition](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/cde-themed-competition-security-for-the-internet-of-things/competition-document-security-for-the-internet-of-things) running for research
- There is an [IoT Security Foundation](https://iotsecurityfoundation.org/) which has some white papers at least
- You might also check out the Common Criteria "Evaluated Assurance Levels". There is an overview with respect to embedded devices [here](http://rtcmagazine.com/articles/view/100121).
- Some recommendations on [Securing Industrial Embedded Devices](http://www.automation.com/pdf_articles/Embedded_Cybersecurity.pdf) may be useful.

The approaches should, of course, mirror any other security driven approach. Though we have some added twists for IoT:

- Embedded devices may not have sufficient power to maintain standard security protocols as they can't always cope with the encryption overheads.
- Embedded devices may be difficult to upgrade making it hard or sometimes impossible to fix security issues discovered after deployment.

One area where I'm trying to make a difference is to try and get standard contracts changed to require vendors to ensure that devices can be upgraded after deployment to keep them current and to fix security issues. So we shouldn't assume that issues and fixes always have to be technical.

---

Just a note about this answer. Because of the question, the answer is inevitably a set of links to other information - normally frowned upon in Stack. It is likely that these links will drift over time which is why I've tried to give the titles where possible so they can be searched for.